# Mercurial Rebase Scenario

Tags: mercurial, rebase

I've read the [RebaseProject](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseProject) page and tried a non-trivial example
(not rebasing a complete branch). It's similar to the case *rebase D on
I* of the scenario B.

Here's the situation before the rebase:

```
default : 0 ----- 2
            \
feature :     1 ----- 3
```

Now I'd like to rebase `3` on `2`, giving:

```
default : 0 ----- 2 ----- 3
            \
feature :     1
```

Unfortunately the exact commands aren't given in the [RebaseProject](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseProject)
page, but from my understanding of the usage synopsis it should be:

```
hg rebase --source 3 --dest 2
```

But somehow my understanding must be flawed, because I get a rebase combined with a merge:

```
default : 0 ----- 2 ----- 3
            \           /
feature :     1 -------
```

Why is that?

Commands to reproduce the scenario:

```
hg init
touch a
hg add a
hg commit -m "added a"
hg branch feature
touch b
hg add b
hg commit -m "added b on feature"
hg up -C default
touch c
hg add c
hg commit -m "added c on default"
hg up -C feature
echo "feature" >> a
hg commit -m "changed a on feature"
hg rebase --source 3 --dest 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scenario looks very similar to part `rebase G onto I` of `scenario B` of the [Rebase Project](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseProject) Scenarios:

> **Scenario B**
> ...
>
> [image: scenario B originally]
> ...
>
> rebase G onto I
>
> [image: rebase G onto I]

In your scenario, `D` == `1`, `I` == `2` and `G` == `3`.  After rebasing, `3` maintains its relationship to `1` just like `G'` maintained its relationship to `D`.  This is because `D` is *not* an ancestor of `I` and:

> Note: Rebase drops a parent relationship only if the parent is an ancestor of target.

You really want to remove that relationship, then, according to the docs, you need a *development version* to get the `--detach` option:

> Using a development version is available the new --detach option that drops this relationship.
>
> [image: new --detach option]

Comment: Thanks! Maybe a development version isn't needed anymore? I had a look a my version (1.5, I suppose I should upgrade) and it does the `--detach` option just fine, with the desired outcome.

Comment: @pesche - Yeah, I tried to see what rev was needed and I couldn't tell.  Guess the docs need to be updated.

Comment: I think the problem is mistaking the RebaseProject wiki page for the docs.  That was a design document for an external (to Mercurial core development) project last summer.  The rebase command itself is the documentation.