# Mercurial command to delete older branch

Tags: mercurial

This is my workflow
I have a branch that needs to get update.
So before working i do hg sync and that syncs with p4head  but creates a new branch .
So once I do hg xl I see something like

```
@xxxxxx bugid: working changes(A) 
|
|
|
|.   xxxxx:bugidworking changes(c) 
|  / 
| xxxxxx  bugid:working changes(b)
o /
```

What I want to do is eliminate b and c but keep a

Is there a dry run that I can test?

Comment: To clarify, do you really mean to delete the work done on b and c? Or do you mean that you want to combine b and c with A so that they don't show up as separate branches anymore?

Comment: The latter is a better option where I can combine changes of b and c into A. Also is there a way we can delte the changes b and c after we've merged?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete multiple heads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435811/how-to-delete-multiple-heads)

Comment: Or an alternative is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573916/mercurial-rebase-scenario